# take a break for a few months

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I have been studying English for over five years.
But the process wasn't continuous.I often took a break for a few months.I don't know how to write the preceeding sentence so that it wouldn't sound unnatural.I have several options:

> 1. I have been studying English for over five years, with a few months' break every now and then.

> I have been studying English for over five years. But there often were breaks of several months.

> I have been studying English for over five years. But I often took a break for a few months.

> I have been studying English for over five years. But I often took a few months' break.

I think the third sentence is the best. Also I really would appreciate if you could suggest a better option.

Answer (score 2):

As a native English speaker they all sound OK to me. I don't think I would prefer one over any other. However you could possibly simplify it. How about

> I have been studying English on and off for 5 years.
> or
> I have been studying English intermittently for 5 years.

If you don't like that, the sentences could be simplified to

> I have been studying English for 5 years with frequent breaks of a few
> months.

Comment: Thank you very much.That is exactly what I wanted.